# cannot convert argument 1 from 'DWORD' to 'DWORD &&'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

some one know how to fix this error

> error C2664: 'std::pair
>   std::make_pair(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'DWORD' to 'DWORD &&'

This is the full code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#ifdef __ITEM_LINK
#include "ItemLink.h"
int CLinkedItemMgr::AddLinkedItem(CItemElem *pItem)
{
    if(!pItem)
        return 0;
    m_mapLinkedItems.insert(make_pair<DWORD,CItemElem*>(++m_dwLinkedItemCount,pItem));
    return m_dwLinkedItemCount;
}
CItemElem *CLinkedItemMgr::GetLinkedItem(DWORD dwIndex)
{
    map<DWORD,CItemElem*>::iterator it = m_mapLinkedItems.find(dwIndex);
    if(it == m_mapLinkedItems.end())
        return FALSE;
    return it->second;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> how to fix this error?

Remove the explicit template parameters. Have it like this:

```
m_mapLinkedItems.insert(make_pair(++m_dwLinkedItemCount, pItem));
```

Comment: can the downvoter please explain what is wrong with this answer